# download.file in R leaves out content

Tags: r, download

I used in R

```
download.file('https://www.census.gov/retail/marts/www/marts_current.xls', method='auto', 
  destfile='C:/Users/<my name>/Desktop/test.xls')
```

expecting to see the contents of marts_current.xls in test.xls but much of the content in the source file is left out.

Can someone help me understand why? How can I get the whole file?

Comment: @MrFlick That worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: I get a warning message from my "xls client" (LibreOffice) about macros that were not executed, but using "wb" has no effect on the size of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel `xls` files are binary files and care should be taken to download them as such. the default for `download.files` is to assume they are text files. You can control this with the `mode=` flag. Use

```
download.file('https://www.census.gov/retail/marts/www/marts_current.xls', method='auto', 
  destfile='C:/Users/<my name>/Desktop/test.xls', mode="wb")
```